# Decoupling cap for self-powered LED matrix and LED strip

Tags: power, led, capacitors

Should I add a decoupling capacitor to [my RGB 16x32 LED matrix powered directly via the 5V pin](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36094/directly-powering-a-single-32x16-rgb-led-matrix-without-external-psu)?

When I display a spectrogram, the current load is fluctuating quickly in the **100-250 mA** range (on average, the full range is 50-300 mA).

If yes, which capacitor should I pick for this purpose?

I have 0.01 μF, 0.1 μF ceramic and 1 μF, 2.2 μF, 4.7 μF, 10 μF, 100 μF electrolytic caps.

EDIT: I'm also interested to know about [this WS2812B LED strip](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/WS2812B-5050-RGB-LED-Flexible-Strip-1M-5M-30-60-144-150-300LED-Waterproof-Non-Waterproof/32800442714.html) i've connected to the 5 V pin to another Arduino.

After reducing the brightness it has similar current consumption and fluctuation of the LED matrix.

In [this tutorial they suggest to add a 1000 μF cap](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ws2812-breakout-hookup-guide), but in my case the currents are much smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no need. The matrix already has plenty of decoupling on it, including a large electrolytic for the incoming power and a small ceramic on each of the chips.

Comment: Possibly. The LEDs are "active" in that they have drive circuits in them. They *should* have decoupling with the LEDs in the strips. It can be good to provide a large reservoir capacitor for that though (the equivalent of the electrolytic on your matrix).

Comment: i've checked the led strip and indeed it has small caps near each WS2812B chip.